# NextGEN Gallery - open all images on page in fancybox

Tags: customization, images, plugin-nextgen-gallery

For now, I am not using NextGen Gallery. For now I am adding `class="fancybox"` and `rel="gallery"` to each image and it opens all images within a page in fancybox. However, client wants to start using it. I have to figure out if it can be used also for this purpose.

Can I use NextGEN Gallery for this scenario:

- I have Pages with images and text
- Images are floated throughout the text
- I need images to be opened in fancybox (for example, if I press first image it will open all images on page in fancybox)

I do understand how to create NextGEN Gallery and show a gallery on page, but I am not able to understand how can I show single images from gallery throughout a Page and then open them in fancybox.

Comment: what about on non-gallery type images, where you have no image id? This used to work just fine in older versions of ngg...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NGG can be used exactly like you described it.

under *Other Settings* you find the *Lightbox Effects* where you can select *Fancybox*, and click *Show Advanced Options*. That's where you can find/set `class="fancybox" rel="gallery"` and you're good to go.

[image]

To show single images you can use the shortcode `[singlepic id=47 ...]`, for instance.

Comment: So, I should use singlepic and add class=fancybox and rel=gallery for them?

Comment: Well, I just stated that NGG has built-in fancybox support, and how you can display a single image. What you actually do is up to you. If you want to stick with `class="fancybox" rel="gallery"` you can do so in the option section/tab shown above. The default settings, however, work as well. That's how NGG has it set up.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But how I can show all single pics in fancybox way? I do understand those fancybox settings for galleries, but not singlepics. How to display all singlepicks onpage in one fancybox?

Comment: Did you try the above? This **is** how it's done. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Work with the options found under Gallery > Other Options > Lightbox Effects ... "What must the lightbox be applied to?"

These will allow other images not in the NextGEN Galleries to be opened into the Lightbox Effect you have chosen.